# Reason for gold lines on old ICs?

Tags: hardware, chip

A lot of older (ceramic) ICs have a gold-plated line extending from the die cover to the edge of the package.  Did this serve a practical purpose or was it just bling?

I suspect that it might be what's left of the lead frame leading to the pad under the soldered die cover.  It would hold the pad in position while the package was molded.  Similarly, the gold plating on the pin-1 notch in the photo below is part of the trimmed lead frame.  This is just a hypothesis; can anyone confirm?

[image: XC68000 DIP package]
Source: Wikipedia/Arnold Reinhold (CC/A-SA)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a ground wire. The way ICs were manufactured back then had the metal cover placed over the die as the last step, and grounding it helps protect the die from static shock and interference.

If you look closely you can see the solder that bonds the strip to the die cover. If you check continuity you will find that both are connected to the IC's ground plane and ground pin(s).

Comment: When would it be grounded though?  The line doesn't connect to any pin.

Comment: It connects to the exposed ground plane on the side of the IC.

Comment: Got it.  Are the covers always grounded?

Comment: I guess they don't have to be, there is a cost to it so if it wasn't necessary for that particular part they might skip it. It depends how sensitive it is, what the application is, that kind of thing. Manufacturers quickly moved to plastic packages once they became practical.

Comment: Ceramic vs. plastic isn't just a matter of practicality of manufacture.  Ceramic packaging is still used today for a variety of reasons including its suitability for high-temperature use, superior hermetic sealing, and mechanical isolation of the die from the package.

Comment: I think some ICs use that as additional heat sink too, sometimes also 2 bendable wings where connected to it from the sides especially for DIL14 packages. Its not always gold ... but its always metalic

Comment: @Spektre Do you have a link to such a package?

Comment: @AlexHajnal it looked like this [MBA 810](https://aukro.cz/io-zesilovace-40ks-tesla-mba-810-mda-2020-6928515132) but those are plastic ...

Comment: @Spektre Interesting, thanks.  Now that I think of it I think I've also seen ones that look like the tab of a TO-220 grafted onto the end of a DIP-14.  Can't recall a part number though.

Comment: @AlexHajnal it was common for analog amplifiers ... the one I linked (MBA810) was familiar for its autodestructive properties... the one MDA2010 next to it was much much better ...

Comment: MBA810 is a high power (up to 10W depending on manufacturer) amplifier. The 'wings' aren't ment as ground (although they are connected), but for cooling. They do not go over the IC (like the cap) but below to transfer heat.

Comment: Also, the metal cap is **never** atatched to the die inside, as the upper side of a die contains circuitry and a metal cap will carry a high chance of shortcuting.  Heat for dissapation is taken from the lower side. That's why modern CPUs are flip mounted, so heat transfer can be aproved ( also it allows more connections, as now pins may also connect to pads inside the chip, not just aroudn the border.

Comment: @Raffzahn One thing that's fairly popular today amongst overclockers is to remove the metal lid from a CPU, place (hopefully non-electrically conductive) heat-conductive paste over the die, then replace the cover.  This allows for better heat transfer than you'd get through pure radiative or convective cooling.  I believe the term they use is "delidding".

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not "bling". Since gold is (obviously) expensive, there is only one reason it's used in electrical circuits: it's because it doesn't corrode (oxidize), and therefore it makes for the best interconnects. There are better conductors out there, such as silver (the best), but they all have issues with corrosion to some extent or another. Think of the "tarnish" that quickly builds-up on any silver that gets exposed to oxygen. But you can drop a piece of gold in the ocean and come back a year later and it still won't have any oxidation on it whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing.SE! This doesn’t answer the question, which is specifically about the gold line extending along the top of the IC’s package, not the use of gold in general.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I thought my answer was implied. As several people mentioned the connections made to this chip (whether electrical, or for thermal dispersion), gold will always maximize connection quality over the life of a product.

Comment: You can edit your answer to add something like "for this ground line" so it does answer the question, instead of just being a footnote to the other answer.